# Clearing Angular Router queryParams

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Currently I have a displayed page, the URL thereof being the following:

`http://localhost:4200/alert?sid=success`

Inside that page there's an `a` link, as follows:

`<a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>`

I want the user to no longer see `?sid=success` when they go back home. I tried using `[queryParams]="{}"` and `[queryParamsHandling]=""` with no success.

Comment: it should reset query params when navigating to the other url, can you add more details? how does initial and the final ulr look like?

Comment: Actually the initial AND final URLs do not change at all, that's the weird thing; so both are `http://localhost:4200/alert?sid=success`

Comment: do not change after what?

Comment: After clicking on the link :)

Comment: try logging events, what does it show?

Comment: Router events you mean? Ok, I'll need a little time for that since I'm already in the middle of another part of the code lol -- I actually thought it was going to be a parameter I'm missing somewhere.

Comment: but the route is not changed, that is the problem, yeah, check events

Answer (score 0):

To remove **ALL** query parameters, do:

```
$location.search({});
```

To remove **ONE** particular query parameter, do:

```
$location.search('queryParam', null);
```